# HTML5 form display [object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement] instead of actual result of addition of two numbers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, netbeans

I'm new to html5 and javascript and is writing a simple form using html5 and javascript. When I press run in netbeans, the form appears in chromo as expected, but when I enter two numbers and press add, instead of displaying `3` in the result colume, `[object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement]` is displayed instead.

[image]

Could someone please tell me why this is happening? How can I fix this error?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href=""><!--this is to be removed for production code, its been placed here because otherwise netbeans produce error message-->

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function addTwoNumbers() {
                var firstNumber = document.getElementById("txtFirstNumber").valueOf();
                var secondNumber = document.getElementById("txtSecondNumber").valueOf();

                document.getElementById("txtResult").value = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            First number<br>
            <input type="text" ID="txtFirstNumber"><br>
            Second number<br>
            <input type="text" ID="txtSecondNumber"><br>
            Result:<br>
            <input type="text" ID="txtResult"><br>
            <br>
            <input type="button" value='add' id='btnAdd' onclick="addTwoNumbers()" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [CodePen of your code to play with](http://codepen.io/anthonyastige/pen/VjPOeR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `value` property as [`Object.prototype.valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) method returns the primitive value of the specified object(In your case, a `DOMElement`)

Also cast `input-value` to `Number` and then manipulate because `Element.value` returns a `String` and `+` will concatenate those values than `adding` them!

[**`Unary plus (+)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()), *The `unary plus operator` precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a `number`, if it isn't already.*

```js
function addTwoNumbers() {
  var firstNumber = +document.getElementById("txtFirstNumber").value;
  var secondNumber = +document.getElementById("txtSecondNumber").value;
  //Output of `valueOf()`
  console.log(document.getElementById("txtFirstNumber").valueOf());
  document.getElementById("txtResult").value = firstNumber + secondNumber;
}
```

```html
<form>
  First number
  <br>
  <input type="text" ID="txtFirstNumber">
  <br>Second number
  <br>
  <input type="text" ID="txtSecondNumber">
  <br>Result:
  <br>
  <input type="text" ID="txtResult">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value='add' id='btnAdd' onclick="addTwoNumbers()" />
</form>
```

Comment: i'm always amazed by how helpful people are on stackoverflow! Thank you so much for helping out!!

Comment: @TonyStark, I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 2):

Use `.value` instead of `.valueOf()`

http://codepen.io/anthonyastige/pen/RRKmrz

```
var firstNumber = document.getElementById("txtFirstNumber").value
var secondNumber = document.getElementById("txtSecondNumber").value
```

Comment: Yeah super quick for little demos :)  There's a number of things like CodePen out there, it's one of the new ones I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var firstNumber = document.getElementById("txtFirstNumber").value;
                var secondNumber = document.getElementById("txtSecondNumber").value;
```

> > Use value not valueOf

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out! really appreciate it!